populating C# Winform DatagridView from MySQL but the records are per row (transposed)



Description
Code
Debit
Credit




Electricity Expenses
101020220
1,000.00



Rent Expenses
10102030
5,000.00



Fuel and Oil
110201010
2,000.00



Receivables
10301020

8,000.00


Grand Total

8,000.00
8,000.00



I want to achieve something like this. This is really easy with excel but I am trying to do this in C# Winform.
My MySQL Tables:

UACS (this contains ID, Description, and Code) <-- used in populating comboboxes
TransactionsCR (this contains ID, Description, Code, Amount)
TransactionsDB (this contains ID, Description, Code, Amount)

Can't post any codes yet since I don't know where to start. I'm planning to add "static" rows that prints "Electricity Exp", "Rent Exp", etc. But what will my SQL query look like? Unless I put query on each row. Something like:
select sum(Amount) as Rent Expenses from TransactionsCR where Code = '10102030'
select sum(Amount) as Rent Expenses from TransactionsDB where Code = '10102030'
select sum(Amount) as Receivables from TransactionsCR where Code = '10301020'
select sum(Amount) as Receivables from TransactionsDB where Code = '10301020'

Another approach is to setup controls that contains 2 labels (description and code) and 2 textboxes (fetch data from debit and credit respectively) per row
But my problem is, I have 150 of theses codes. so 150x4=600 controls on a single form. This will be sluggish as hell to load.

Answers to the duplicate question show you how you can pivot dynamic number of columns in mysql. However, this is unlikely to scale well. Consider using some kind of a MI tool or in-memory data transformation tool instead.

Am I missing something or are you not actually looking for a pivot? If your target result is the table with "Description, Code, Debit, Credit" you can do this with aggregations or dependent subquery. Do you know "join" and/or "group by"? Since the question is closed: try something like select Description, Code, (select sum(Amount) from TransactionsDB d where d.code = u.code) as Debit, (select sum(Amount) from TransactionsCR c where c.code = u.code) as Credit from UACS u. There are other, nicer, faster ways, you may need indexes, but this might get you started. Don't add 600 controls!
